# Problems with startup.bat of apache-tomcat-7.0.54

Tags: tomcat7

I downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.54 of http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi, the binary distributions 32-bit Windows zip (pgp, md5). 
I went to apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin\startup.bat on my machine; and did two clicks on this file but when I try localhost:8080, Tomcat is not up and doesn´t show errors.

I had installed JDK 1.6 and I have other version of Tomcat 5.5 and when I try \apache-tomcat-5.5.27\bin\startup.bat the tomcat works perfectly
sorry for my english is a little bad. I wait your help, thanks so much.

Comment: make sure are you set environment variable of jdk and jre?.you extract manually zip file.so,try to set Environment Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open "Command Prompt", go do apache folder and try to start up it using prompt. Post results, please.

You could post the log file too.

Comment: Hi David, I try to run this in command prompt and I got it:                                                             Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\Common\Java5.0\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\java\a
pache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"